# Python/Django with Stripe: Error in Post request in creating stripe subscription

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

This is my first time using stripe does this look familiar to anyone?
So I am able to see that a token is being created upon payment, but instead of being redirected to my template, i throws this error below!

### ERROR

```
>**InvalidRequestError:**
>Request req_d5BvUPtlpLrsG5: Received unknown parameter: source
>Request Method:    POST
>Django Version:    2.1
>Exception Type:    InvalidRequestError
>Exception Value:   
>**Request req_d5BvUPtlpLrsG5: Received unknown parameter: source**
```

**CODE**

```
def PaymentView(request):

    user_membership = get_user_membership(request)

    selected_membership = get_selected_membership(request)

    publishKey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY

    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            token = request.POST['stripeToken']
            subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
              customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id,# id on User Membership Model
              items=[
                {
                  "plan": selected_membership.stripe_plan_id,
                },
              ],
              source=token # 4242424242424242
            )

            return redirect(reverse('memberships:update-transactions',
                kwargs={
                    'subscription_id': subscription.id
                }))

        except stripe.error.CardError as e:
            messages.info(request, "Your card has been declined")

    context = {
        'publishKey': publishKey,
        'selected_membership': selected_membership
    }

    return render(request, "path/templategoeshere.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to remove the source=token key value pair in the stripe.Subscription.create() method.

So, you should have something more like:

```
def PaymentView(request):

  user_membership = get_user_membership(request)

  selected_membership = get_selected_membership(request)

  publishKey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY

  import stripe
  stripe.api_key = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2"

  if request.method == "POST":
    try:
      token = request.POST['stripeToken']
      print(token) # WHAT IS PRINTED OUT HERE?
      subscription = stripe.Subscription.create(
        customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
        items=[
          {
            "plan": selected_membership.stripe_plan_id,
          },
        ]
      )

      return redirect(reverse('memberships:update-transactions', kwargs={ 'subscription_id': subscription.id }))

    except stripe.error.CardError as e:
      messages.info(request, "Your card has been declined")
```

The accepted arguments for the stripe.Subscription.create() object method are: customer (required), application_fee_percent, billing, billing_cycle_anchor, coupon, days_until_due, items, metadata, prorate, tax_precent, trial_end, trial_from_plan and trial_period_days (all optional).

This may help: https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#create_subscription

Comment: thats weird im watching i video that was made on july 9, 2018 and he is literally using it and making it work. Infact here is the link to his views page. https://github.com/justdjango/video-membership/blob/master/memberships/views.py

Comment: and here is the video, go to 2hrs in the video and start watching

Comment: Yes - how odd! Did you try it with it removed? As unlikely as it sounds - it may have changed in the intervening time. Could you do some quick print debug for me and use the following: `print(token)` after token is declared from the POST['stripeToken'] and then immediately `print(type(token))` for me...

Comment: What version of the API are you using? Did you upgrade at all? It looks like the `source` param on this call was deprecated in the latest version. https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2018-07-27

Comment: @teaglebuilt See the above comment from "duck" - it looks like it was deprecated in the last version. Did everything work ok with the changes I suggested?

Comment: @duck So i uninstalled stripe and then installed it to Stripe version 1.48. which is a previous version that is equivelant to the tutorial, yet the issue still persists.

Comment: @winduplordvexxos yes i will debug it now and send it to you

Comment: Ok so this is the version which lines up with the tutorial requirements: Name: stripe
Version: 1.84.0
Summary: Python bindings for the Stripe API
Home-page: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python
Author: Stripe
Author-email: support@stripe.com
License: MIT

Comment: also @winduplordvexxos I forgot to clarify, in your first response. I tried to erase source as you suggested and then got this error: Request req_3OGguJ5z9oU2Ap: This customer has no attached payment source

Comment: @teaglebuilt - I reckon you have an older version of the stripe API python wrapper installed, so perhaps try pip install stripe-python —upgrade . You’re getting the one error because the Stripe API has changed (hence the error at the request stage). And your new error is because the wrapper version you have expects to have source. I’d try upgrading your stripe-python wrapper...

Comment: @winduplordvexxos so when i tried "pip install stripe-python --upgrade"
I get Collecting stripe-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement stripe-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for stripe-python

So if i downgraded my stripe version to 1.84.....i thought there was only one module of stripe to install?

Comment: @winduplordvexxos i dont have stripe-python installed, are you suggesting i do?

Comment: @winduplordvexxos. Your right so I read through the docs and found this.
The subscription endpoints no longer support the source parameter. If you want to change the default source for a customer, instead use the source creation API to add the new source and then the customer update API to set it as the default.

Comment: @teaglebuilt - Yeh the stripe API went through a pretty major change in the last few weeks so this is what is causing the disparity. Their docs are pretty comprehensive so to have it omitted would be very unusual. I guess my answer can be accepted as correct now? :)

Comment: @teaglebuilt Don't forget to `import stripe` and to add your stripe API key as show in the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the tutorial and the way I tried to solve this was by creating a source object instead of token object in the Javascript. So if you look at JS code below (copied from STRIPE API docs) you can see its now createSource.The source == the CC number which will be attached to their account.

Back in Django I create a stripe.Customer.create_source and then subsequently the stripe.Subscription.create after I have the card saved to account.. Since the default in Stripe Subscriptions is to auto charge subscription with the card attached to customer account it should charge the card immediately.

Just grab the source_id similar to how you did with token from the form in Django and then pass into stripe.Customer.create_source (obviously grab your Stripe customer id to pass in ass well).

```
  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createSource(card).then(function(result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the source to your server
        stripeSourceHandler(result.source);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            source = request.POST['stripeSource']
            stripe.Customer.create_source(
                user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
                source=source)

            stripe.Subscription.create(
                customer=user_membership.stripe_customer_id,
                items=[
                    {
                    "plan": selected_membership.stripe_plan_id,
                    },
                ])
            messages.success(request, 'Your payment was completed!')    
            # stripe.Customer.create_source(type='')
        except stripe.CardError as e:
            messages.info(request, 'Your card has been declined!')
```

**Note: Per their docs you can pass in the customer data (address, etc) in the JS object like below. You could maybe add to the form to have user enter in credit card address data etc so it passes into their stripe customer account if you want to.**

```
// Create a source or display an error when the form is submitted. 
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
var ownerInfo = {
  owner: {
    name: 'Jenny Rosen',
    address: {
      line1: 'Nollendorfstraße 27',
      city: 'Berlin',
      postal_code: '10777',
      country: 'DE',
    },
    email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com'
  },
};
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createSource(card, ownerInfo).then(function(result) {
  //rest of stripe js code.....
```

Hopefully this helps!!